# is Vagrant suitable for beginners that are not tech savvy?

Tags: vagrant

I'm planning to teach a group a people how to setup a website using WordPress. Those people have some basic computer usage knowledge : they can surf the web, write emails, install software on their computer, ... But they are absolutely not developers. And the training does not aim to teach them development.

But I want them to be able to setup a fully working local web environment or their computer that runs on Windows. I was planning to use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org), but I'm wondering if Vagrant is not more suitable. I could prepare a box with a lot of tools already included, and they will just have to install it. Interaction with the server would take place only via http and FTP (no ssh needed).

Is it possible to create a batch file that they can click on to launch the Vagrant ? If properly configured, is that as easy to use as that for absolute beginners ?

Comment: @Febien Quatravoux - this is open to people's opinions so you probably won't get a definite answer. Personally, I would say no as vagrant can go horribly wrong

Answer (score 0):

from what you describe there is almost no vagrant thing, you would be responsible to make the vagrant box and the vagrantfile, and you will not expose your students to vagrant. only thing is that they would need to have this bat file on their desktop (the only command that it will need to run is `vagrant up`, make sure to expose the [`vagrant cwd` variable](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/environmental-variables.html)) and the server will be up and running.

The main advantage I see then is that you will completely make your students in the same situation they will be with their production system. they will face the same tool (FTP, wordpress admin ...) on an environment (more or less) identical to a production environment.

Comment: OK, great so I can setup the training computer like that. But I want them to be able to reproduce this configuration on their own computer at home, with little help from me. Is it "exposing the students to Vagrant" to let them download and install it ?

Comment: I would say that as long it consists of 'download and install vagrant, git clone project, and vagrant up' would still be fine, it all depends of our audience but it still basic